# C print wide chars in colors in iTerm2

Tags: c, colors, iterm2, widechar

I have a wide char `wchar_t*` string and I'd like to print it in color, with `write(3)`

something like this:

```
write(1, L"\x1b[31m", 5 * sizeof(wchar_t));
write(1, L"BLA", 3 * sizeof(wchar_t));
write(1, L"\x1b[0m", 5 * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Prints `[31mBLA[0m` without colors.

And something like this:

```
write(1, "\x1b[31m", 5);
write(1, "BLA", 3);
write(1, "\x1b[0m", 5);
```

Correctly prints `BLA` in `red`.

Any idea how I can print `wide char` strings in color ?

EDIT: It seems to print correctly in `Terminal.app` but not in `iTerm2` any idea why ?

Comment: I just pasted the first code an it prints BLA colored. I'm using linux with bash in KDE terminal emulator.

Comment: really :/ On OS X with iTerm2 it prints without colors -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this just isn't implemented yet in iTerm2, I've opened an issue here: [iTerm2 issue 3460](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=3460&thanks=3460&ts=1427153432).

A Milestone has been set to implement this I'll update the answer when it's done.